# EWS Connections Issues - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: vb.net, exchangewebservices

Trying to connect to exchange 2010 SP1 using EWS & VB.Net. When i try to use autodiscovery it works just fine. The problem being is it connects to my local exchange mailbox and thats not what i need. We have a mailbox that the exchange admins set up that all the programmers can connect to (call it TestMailbox). So when i do:

```
exchange.AutoDiscoverUrl("TestMailbox@MyDomain.com")
```

It connects to my local mailbox rather than the "TestMailbox". I got the password for the TestMailbox NT account from our admin and tried all of the following:

```
exchange.Credentials = New WebCredentials("TestMailbox@MyDomain.com", "Password")      


exchange.Credentials = New WebCredentials("TestMailbox", "Password") 

exchange.Credentials = New WebCredentials("TestMailbox", "Password","MyDomain")

exchange.Credentials = New WebCredentials("MyDomain\TestMailbox", "Password")
```

all of them fail. Say my NT username on my local net work is "User" i even tried:

```
exchange.Credentials = New WebCredentials("User@MyDomain.com", "MyPassword")
```

and it failed. I have been using the following [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597939%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) for reference.

Edit 1: i have tried all the above with NetworkCredential rather than WebCredential and it still fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured it out. TheTestMailbox & ProdMailbox domain accounts were both setup to only allow certain computer to login locally.